# Getting transformed X values from OLS model using statsmodels

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to do a linear regression. With the results I want to multiply each *x* with its own estimated coefficient: *x*<sub>i</sub>·*β*<sub>i</sub>.

However, I am doing a lot of transformations on *x*<sub>i</sub>.

For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

def log_plus_1(x):
    return np.log(x + 1.0)

df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()
formule = 'Lottery ~ pow(Literacy,2) + log_plus_1(Wealth)'
mod = smf.ols(formula=formule, data=df)
res = mod.fit()
res.params
```

Now I would need `pow(Literacy, 2)` and `log_plus_1(Wealth)`. But since they go into the model, I was hoping to get them out of there too. Instead of transforming the data from the original dataset.

In R I would use `res$model` to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored as attributes of the model, e.g. the design matrix is `mod.exog`, the dependent or response variable is `mod.endog`.

(I'm not sure I remember correctly the details of the following: The data that patsy returns after creating the transformed design matrix should, in this case, be a pandas DataFrame, and should be stored in `mod.data.orig_exog` or something like that.)

`res.predict` automatically handles the transformation, i.e. patsy uses the formula information to transform the data for the explanatory variables in prediction in the same way as the data was transformed in creating the model.
`predict` only returns the prediction and not the internally transformed predict `exog`.

Comment: @SimonTeggelaar It's the core feature of this site, which is covered in the very first section of the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (which admittedly is hard to find if you are looking for it as I was right now, but it should have been presented to you when you created your account).